# Trying to get the SVG items to stay in place

Tags: html, svg

I have four circles on a grid with a X & Y axis. The idea is to have each circle to stay in place and they need to rotoate 306 degrees. The way I have it now is all of the circles are in the proper position, but they are all moving in a circle that goes outside of the graph.

```html
<svg width="500" height="500">
          
            <defs>
              <g id="stopSign">
                <ellipse cx="0" cy="0" rx="50" ry="50" 
                  stroke="#000000" stroke-width="2" fill="#FFC0CB"> 
                </ellipse>
                <ellipse cx="0" cy="55" rx="5" ry="5" 
                  fill="#FF0000"> 
                </ellipse>
                <ellipse cx="0" cy="-55" rx="5" ry="5" 
                  fill="#0000FF"> 
                </ellipse>
                <text x=-30 y=5 font-family="san-serif" 
                  font-size="24px" fill="#00000">
                  Suresh
                </text>
              </g>
            </defs>
          
            <line x1="0" y1="250" x2="500" y2="250" stroke="#000000"></line>
            <line x1="250" y1="0" x2="250" y2="500" stroke="#000000"></line>
                    
            <g transform="translate(300, 200)">
              <use xlink:href="#stopSign">
                <animateTransform attributeName="transform" begin="0s" dur="10s" type="rotate" from="0 150 150" to="360 150 150" repeatCount="indefinite" degrees="0"></animateTransform>
              </use>
            </g> 
            <g transform="translate(300, 300)">
              <use xlink:href="#stopSign">
                <animateTransform attributeName="transform" begin="0s" dur="10s" type="rotate" from="0 150 150" to="360 150 150" repeatCount="indefinite" degrees="0"></animateTransform>
              </use>
            </g> 
            <g transform="translate(200, 200)">
              <use xlink:href="#stopSign">
                <animateTransform attributeName="transform" begin="0s" dur="10s" type="rotate" from="0 150 150" to="360 150 150" repeatCount="indefinite" degrees="0"></animateTransform>
              </use>
            </g> 
            <g transform="translate(200, 300)">
              <use xlink:href="#stopSign">
                <animateTransform attributeName="transform" begin="0s" dur="10s" type="rotate" from="0 150 150" to="360 150 150" repeatCount="indefinite" degrees="0"></animateTransform>
              </use>
            </g> 
          
          </svg>
```

Tried to change the translate assignment but no luck.

Comment: The shapes you have are rotating around the point 150 150 (as in `from="0 150 150" to="360 150 150"`). In order to see the rotation point add `<circle cx="150" cy="150" r="3" />` inside the transformed group.  To make them rotate as you wish change the rotation point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change all **'from="0 150 150" to="360 150 150"'** s (Because it means rotate around an ellipse scaled 150x150) to **'from="0 0 0" to="360 0 0"'**

It must be

```html
<svg width="500" height="500">
      
        <defs>
          <g id="stopSign">
            <ellipse cx="0" cy="0" rx="50" ry="50" 
              stroke="#000000" stroke-width="2" fill="#FFC0CB"> 
            </ellipse>
            <ellipse cx="0" cy="55" rx="5" ry="5" 
              fill="#FF0000"> 
            </ellipse>
            <ellipse cx="0" cy="-55" rx="5" ry="5" 
              fill="#0000FF"> 
            </ellipse>
            <text x=-30 y=5 font-family="san-serif" 
              font-size="24px" fill="#00000">
              Suresh
            </text>
          </g>
        </defs>
      
        <line x1="0" y1="250" x2="500" y2="250" stroke="#000000"></line>
        <line x1="250" y1="0" x2="250" y2="500" stroke="#000000"></line>
                
        <g transform="translate(300, 200)">
          <use xlink:href="#stopSign">
            <animateTransform attributeName="transform" begin="0s" dur="10s" type="rotate" from="0 0 0" to="360 0 0" repeatCount="indefinite" degrees="0"></animateTransform>
          </use>
        </g> 
        <g transform="translate(300, 300)">
          <use xlink:href="#stopSign">
            <animateTransform attributeName="transform" begin="0s" dur="10s" type="rotate" from="0 0 0" to="360 0 0" repeatCount="indefinite" degrees="0"></animateTransform>
          </use>
        </g> 
        <g transform="translate(200, 200)">
          <use xlink:href="#stopSign">
            <animateTransform attributeName="transform" begin="0s" dur="10s" type="rotate" from="0 0 0" to="360 0 0" repeatCount="indefinite" degrees="0"></animateTransform>
          </use>
        </g> 
        <g transform="translate(200, 300)">
          <use xlink:href="#stopSign">
            <animateTransform attributeName="transform" begin="0s" dur="10s" type="rotate" from="0 0 0" to="360 0 0" repeatCount="indefinite" degrees="0"></animateTransform>
          </use>
        </g> 
      
  </svg>
```